# Share Hibernate connection with other libraries

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, c3p0

I'm writing a web application in Java and use Hibernate to map the database with my java objects. In Hibernate I connect to the database using C3PO pool. Now I need to schedule some tasks. Herefore I will use Quartz. Now the scheduled tasks will be stored in the database. It is possible to share the connection pool of C3PO with Quartz? So that the database settings are in one and the same file and that only one library is responsible to open a databaseconnection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sort of a subjective thing, but suffice it to say, if you want to share the connection you have a number of options.

If you are using spring, define the c3p0 connection pool as a bean and inject it into both the Hibernate session factory and the Quartz scheduler beans.

If you are trying to stay "pure" and not using Spring, you can define your a JNDI based data-source at the container level.

There are some nuances with both approaches.

Unfortunately without indicating how "portable" you are trying to be and what you are currently using beyond just 'java', 'quartz-scheduler' and 'c3p0' as tags an answer will be vague at best.

**EDIT**

Thanks to the OP for adding additional information.

So with regard to that information, if you are using a Dynamic Web Project, you may be able to add a container specific deployment descriptor to WebContent directory.

- For tomcat, META-INF/context.xml
- For Jetty, WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml

With those, you can define a JNDI data source. Refer to the specific container for information on how to do that. Once done, Hibernate and Quartz can be configured to use a JNDI reference for the data source you have configured.

Comment: I'm using Java 8, Hibernate with C3pO, Quartz  in a Dynamic web project (not using Beans). I'm not using any large framework like Spring, ...